# ddev: Call the endpoint of a certain port of the web container from another container

Tags: docker, cypress, shopware, ddev

I set up a Shopware 6 project with ddev. Now I want to write cypress tests for one of my plugins. The shopware testsuite starts a node express server on port 8005 in the web container. I have configured the port for ddev so that I can open the express endpoint in my browser: http://my.ddev.site:8005/cleanup. That is working.

For cypress I have created a new ddev container with a new docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  cypress:
    container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-cypress
    image: cypress/included:4.10.0
    tty: true
    ipc: host
    links:
      - web:web
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=https://web
      - DISPLAY
    labels:
      com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
      com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
    volumes:
      # Project root
      - ../shopware:/project
      # Storefront and Administration
      - ../shopware/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Storefront/Resources/app/storefront/test/e2e:/e2e-Storefront
      - ../shopware/vendor/shopware/platform/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/test/e2e:/e2e-Administration
      # Custom plugins
      - ../shopware/custom/plugins/MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/administration/test/e2e:/e2e-MyPlugin
      # for Cypress to communicate with the X11 server pass this socket file
      # in addition to any other mapped volumes
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
```

I can now successfully open the cypress interface and I see my tests. The problem is now, that always before a cypress test is executed, the express endpoint is called (with the URL from above) and the cypress container seems to has no access to the endpoint. This is the output:

```
cy.request() failed trying to load:

http://my.ddev.site:8005/cleanup

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8005

-----------------------------------------------------------

The request we sent was:

Method: GET
URL: http://my.ddev.site:8005/cleanup
```

So I can call this endpoint in my browser, but cypress can't. Is there any configuration in the cypress container missing to call the port 8005 from the web container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to the cypress service:

```
external_links:
  - "ddev-router:${DDEV_HOSTNAME}"
```

and then your http URL will be accessed through the router via ".ddev.site".

If you need a trusted https URL it's a little more complicated, but for http this should work fine.